# Fetch and decode JSON from api.coinmarketcap.com

Tags: php, json, api

How can I get variables "price_usd" for bitcoin & ethereum from JSON url https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker

This works:

```
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";
$fgc = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($fgc, TRUE);
$lastPrice = $json[0]["price_usd"];
echo $lastPrice;
```

However, I would like to do something like this:

```
<?php 

$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";
$fgc = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($fgc, TRUE);

function price($ticker) {
    foreach($json[] as $item) {
        if($item->id == $ticker) {
            echo $item->price_usd;
        }
    }
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo price("bitcoin");?>

<?php echo price("etheruem");?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plaese provide a **minimal** example of the JSON in your question, rather than the link :-)

Comment: What should `$json[]["price_usd"]` do? Add to an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for this:

```
$json = json_decode($fgc, TRUE);
// following line will create assoc array as key => value for 'price_usd' as key and 'id' as value
$js = array_column($json, 'price_usd', 'id');
echo $js["bitcoin"];
```

General Function:

```
$decoded_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"), TRUE);

function price($curr) {
    global $decoded_json;
    $js = array_column($decoded_json, 'price_usd', 'id');
    return $js[$curr];
}

echo price("bitcoin");
echo price("ethereum");
```

Another solution without global var:

```
// this will create a new request to api.coinmarketcap.com on each call
function price($curr) {
    $decoded_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"), TRUE);
    $js = array_column($decoded_json, 'price_usd', 'id');
    return $js[$curr];
}
```

Now that the question is updated, you can just cast the `$js` to object and use it like an object:

```
$js = (object) $js;
echo $js->bitcoin;
```

Comment: perfect. can you do this in a function to so you can do echo $js("bitcoin")? Is it worth doing one over the other?

Comment: I think you have solved all my issues I think. So say I want to display various prices e.g.

<?php echo price("bitcoin");?>
<?php echo price("etheruem");?>

Does this create 2 requests? Or does it just use the one?

Comment: @Trent Yeah, it will create two requests.

Comment: Without trying to stretch the friendship a little. How wold one turn this into 1 request? Feel free to point me in the right direction rather then waste too much of your time.

Comment: @Trent You can store the request into `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` and use it to avoid multiple request.

Comment: @Trent Check the update :) Now it won't create multiple request when function is called multiple times in a single page.

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was trying to do.